# c# httpwebrequest getResponse() freezes and hangs my program

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, getresponse

I was trying to use httpwebrequest to use a rest like service on a remote server and from the first execution itself, my code was hanging the program. Then I tried it as a console application to make sure it has nothing to do with the program itself but no luck!

```
        string credentialsJson = @"{""username"":""test"",
                                      ""password"":""test"" 
                                   }";

        int tmp = ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://qrua.com/qr/service" + @"/auth/login");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Timeout = 50000 ;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        try
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            writer.Write(credentialsJson);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION:" + e.Message);
        }

        //WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("request:\n" + request.ToString() + "\nresponse:\n" + response.ContentLength);
                response.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EXCEPTION: in sending http request:" + " \nError message:" + e.Message);
        }
```

Tried several things from different forums but it doesnt help. Even a simple console app with the above code hangs the console indefinitely! Any help would be great..

Thanks

Comment: Try specifying request.ContentLength. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736056

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're never closing the `StreamWriter`... so I suspect it's not being flushed. Admittedly I'd expect an error from the server instead of just a hang, but it's worth looking at.

Btw, you don't need to close the response *and* dispose it. Just the `using` statement is enough.

Comment: Why did you mark this as correct, and then in another place you say, "tried closing the writer and it didnt do much" ?

Comment: @Lost Hobbit: I suggest you add a comment to the *question* instead of to my answer - the OP won't get notification of this comment. (Not that the OP has been on Stack Overflow for 11 months anyway...)

Comment: Was using HtmlAgilityPack and following permanent redirects in that library didnt close the underlying response before creating a new.

Comment: This exactly worked for me on the exact problem I was just having.  Thanks @JonSkeet.

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There's not much you can do if the remote server is not responding other than defining a `Timeout` and catch the exception as you did in order to inform the user that the operation cannot complete because the remote site didn't respond:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://qrua.com/qr/service/auth/login");
request.Timeout = 5000;
// If the server doesn't respond within 5 seconds you might catch the timeout exception
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{

}
```

If you don't want to freeze the UI you could use the async version: [BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetresponse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying request.ContentLength.

Before doing:

```
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
        writer.Write(credentialsJson);
```

Try something like this:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(credentialsJson);
        writer.Close();
    }
    request.ContentLength = stream.Length;
}
```