# Why does HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() hang when trying to update an OData service?

Tags: c#, rest, httpwebrequest, odata

I'm writing an OData consumer in c#.  I can successfully delete an entry, but for some reason it simply hangs / freezes on GetResponse() when I try to update.  It even ignores my timeout.  Below is my test code.  Any intelligent suggestions?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""iso-8859-1"" standalone=""yes""?>
<entry xml:base=""http://localhost/odata/service.svc/"" xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"" xmlns:m=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"">
  <id>http://localhost/odata/service.svc/SimpleTests(7)</id>
  <title type=""text""></title>
  <updated>2011-07-18T12:19:43Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel=""edit"" title=""SimpleTest"" href=""SimpleTests(7)"" />
  <category term=""MetastormModel.SimpleTest"" scheme=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"" />
  <content type=""application/xml"">
    <m:properties>
      <d:ID m:type=""Edm.Int32"">7</d:ID>
      <d:varcharcol>EFGH</d:varcharcol>
      <d:intcol m:type=""Edm.Int32"">-44</d:intcol>
      <d:realcol m:type=""Edm.Single"">22.11</d:realcol>
      <d:datetimecol m:type=""Edm.DateTime"">1999-12-31T00:00:00</d:datetimecol>
      <d:imagecol m:type=""Edm.Binary"" m:null=""true"" />
      <d:moneycol m:type=""Edm.Decimal"">1000000.0000</d:moneycol>
      <d:textcol>WOW!</d:textcol>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>");

HttpWebRequest request =
 (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/odata/service.svc/SimpleTests(7)");
request.Method = "PUT";
request.Accept = "application/atom+xml";
request.Timeout = 1000;
request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml;type=entry";
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    doc.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.Close();
}
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling around with Fiddler, I came up with the following solution, which works.  The part that seems to solve the problem is specifying request.ContentLength.  I don't know of a simpler way to get the length, so feel free to comment if you do.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" standalone=""yes""?>
<entry xmlns:d=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"" xmlns:m=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"" xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"">
  <category scheme=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme"" term=""MetastormModel.SimpleTest"" />
  <title />
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <updated>2011-07-19T09:28:03.173654Z</updated>
  <id>http://localhost/odata/service.svc/SimpleTests(7)</id>
  <content type=""application/xml"">
    <m:properties>
      <d:ID m:type=""Edm.Int32"">7</d:ID>
      <d:datetimecol m:type=""Edm.DateTime"">1950-01-01T00:00:00</d:datetimecol>
      <d:imagecol m:type=""Edm.Binary"" m:null=""true"" />
      <d:intcol m:type=""Edm.Int32"">-44</d:intcol>
      <d:moneycol m:type=""Edm.Decimal"">12345.0000</d:moneycol>
      <d:realcol m:type=""Edm.Single"">22.11</d:realcol>
      <d:textcol>Hello There</d:textcol>
      <d:varcharcol>EFGH</d:varcharcol>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>");

HttpWebRequest request =
 (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/odata/service.svc/SimpleTests(7)");
request.Method = "MERGE";
request.Accept = "application/atom+xml,application/xml";
request.Timeout = 20000;
request.ContentType = "application/atom+xml";
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
    {
        doc.WriteTo(writer);
        writer.Close();
    }
    request.ContentLength = stream.Length;
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        doc.WriteTo(writer);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A PUT request does not return any content other than a HTTP code (204 - No Content) for success.

See [this part of the OData spec](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations) for details.

Comment: Thanks for this, but can this piece of information help me in any way? Are you suggesting I try to send a request without waiting for a response?

Comment: Do you have access to the server to see if it is indeed generating a response? Also, tools like Fiddler and some of the OData client tools (for example the Silverlight client) can help you compare your network traffic with the one generated by those tools. I currently don't have an OData service setup to investigate.

Comment: If you add HttpStatusCode code = response.StatusCode inside your using statement, does it reach it and return a value? Or is that what you mean by 'frozen' that it doesn't reach it?

Comment: Yes, it's running on localhost.  Thanks for the suggestions... I'll give them a try.

Comment: "Frozen" means it never gets inside the using.

Comment: Even if you add an executable statement in Debug mode?

Comment: Yip, it just hangs.  If I pause it, it's always on HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()

Comment: Can you please try Fiddler or something similar to see if the client actually sends the request and what the actual response is (if any)?
You can also try the public service http://services.odata.org/(S(readwrite))/OData/OData.svc/ with modified payload. Or using Fiddler to build the request without your client code and try to hit the service (to see if the problem is on the client or on the server)